# jQuery gritter plugin close icon remains hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gritter

I'm using gritter.js to notificate success or error messages. It works but the "X" close-icon remains hidden. I check in CSS rules of the element, they are all right but having no effects.

```js
<script src="/components/jquery.gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/jquery.gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css" />

  /*some other code*/
  switch (window.location.hash) {
    case "#success":
    $.gritter.add({
      title: 'Molto bene!',
      text: "L'operazione è stata eseguita con successo!",
      sticky: true,
      class_name: 'gritter-success gritter-light'
    });
    break;
    case "#error":
    $.gritter.add({
      title: 'Oops!',
      text: "Qualcosa è andato storto. L'operazione non è stata eseguita!",
      class_name: 'gritter-error gritter-light'
    });
    break;
  }
```

The js produce an icon like:
    `<a style="display: none;" class="gritter-close" href="#" tabindex="1">Close Notification</a>`

And the css rules are:

```
.gritter-light .gritter-close {
    background-image: none;
    color: #444;}

//applied onhover
elemento {
    display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late maybe but could it be so that you are using the ace template as well.

I had the same problem recently. Turns out ace template has a css rule that sets the font size of gritter close icon to zero. Simply overriding that css rule fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yes it's correct. I solved the problem as you say. I was using a old version of the template css. Updating that rule all works well.